# C# Copy 2D matrix issue

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a class A:

```
public class A {
    private Point[,] matrix = null;
    private int r, c;

    public Point[,] Matrix
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.matrix == null || this.matrix.Length == 0)
            {
                // Matrix is null or it has no elements on it.
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.matrix;
            }
        }
    }

    public A(int r, int c)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
        this.matrix = new Point[r, c];
    }

    public void InitializeMatrix
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                this.matrix[i, j] = new Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CopyMatrix(out Point[,] copyMatrix)
    {
        if (this.Matrix == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Matrix is null.", "Matrix");
        }

        Point[,] m = new Point[r, c];

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                m[i, j] = this.Matrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        copyMatrix = m;
    }
}
```

Point is a class:

```
public class Point 
{
    public int x, y;

    public Point (int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

So from another class, let's say, B:

```
public class B
{
     private A instanceA;

     public B (A a)
     {
         // imagine a valid not null instance of class A is passed.
         this.instanceA = a;
     }

     private void SomeMethod()
     {
         Point[,] m;
         this.instanceA.CopyMatrix(out m);

         m[2, 4].x = 9;    <--- here is the problem    
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",this.instanceA.Matrix[2, 4].x));
     }
}
```

The problem is:

In SomeMethod method of class B, when I update my local matrix Point[,] m also is updated matrix 'matrix' in class A. If I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(this.instanceA.Matrix[2, 4]);
```

it outputs 9 as well. Why? Its content has been altered as well...

Comment: Point is a class, it's a reference type. Like a pointer in C++. When copying it, you need to create a `new Point()` each time

Comment: @ThomasWeller Ops... and how can I obtain a copy of the matrix and alter the copy without altering the orginal matrix? Could you tell me how or post a little example, please?

Comment: Change `m[i, j] = this.Matrix[i, j];` to `m[i, j] = new Point(this.Matrix[i, j].x,this.Matrix[i, j].y) ;`

Comment: Your `CopyMatrix` method creates a new array but then it populates that array with the points from the array being copied.  So each array contains the same points.

Comment: @ThomasWeller He does; that is contained within the CopyMatrix method

Comment: This code should not produce that result. That leads me to believe you are contaminating the test object somehow. Perhaps you are running the test twice in quick succession and failing to reset it or something of that nature. Can you add the code that passes in the `A` object please?

Comment: @BenWainwright: he does it in InitMatrix() but not in CopyMatrix().

Comment: @ThomasWeller What does `Point[,] m = new Point[r, c]` do then?

Comment: @BenWainwright: it creates the array, it does not create the points. Major difference: it is outside the loop, so there's only one of it (which is correct).  Creating the points themselves needs to be inside the loop, because you want to have many points.

Comment: @ThomasWeller My bad; I see your 'point'. Hur hur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you don't properly understand the difference between a 'reference' type and a 'primitive' type.

## Reference Types vs. Primitive Types

For a primitive type (numbers, like an `int` or a `long`); the variable itself is allocated on the stack and contains the actual numerical value itself. If I do

```
int foo = 1;
int bar;
bar = foo;
```

This allocates space on the stack for a variable named `foo`, assigns it the value `1`, allocates more space on the stack for `bar`, then copies the number `1` into `bar`. Both variables remain independent of each other, so if I now do

```
bar = 4
```

`foo` remains unchanged.

For an object, something a little different is happening. Take the following:

```
class MyObject {
    public int x;
}


// Inside some method somewhere
MyObject foo = new MyObject();
MyObject bar;
foo = bar;
```

In this case what is happening is memory is allocated on the *heap* for an instance of `MyObject`. A *reference variable* named `foo` is then allocated on the stack and initialised with the *memory address* of the `MyObject` that was just created.

This is a crucial point; in this instance `foo` **does not contain the object**, simply a reference to it. This means when on the next line we allocate a new reference type `bar`, the line `foo = bar` is now assigned the *memory address* of the *same allocated object*.

This means we can do the following

```
foo.x = 1;
bar.x = 10;
```

Since foo and bar now both point to the *same memory address*, if we were to print the value of *either* `foo.x` or `bar.x` to the console, the outcome would be 10.

## The Solution

SO, how does this relate to your problem? Easy; your matrix is an array of *references* to `Point` objects, not `Point` objects themselves. So the line in your code

```
m[i, j] = this.Matrix[i, j];
```

Is simply copying these references **to the same `Point` objects** to the new matrix. To solve your problem; change the above line to the following:

```
m[i, j] = new Point(this.Matrix[i, j].x, this.Matrix[i, j].y);
```

What this does instead is to allocate memory on the heap for *entirely new `Point`* objects, and initialise them with the values from the old ones.